# Is it possible to find a lower bound for the ratio of the imaginary part to the real part of the first nontrivial eigenvalue of a finite Markov chain?

Tags: pr.probability

We are considering a continuous-time Markov chain $K$ with a stationary distribution $\pi$. $K$ has a finite state space $\Omega$ with $N$ states. The dynamical equation for the probability distribution $\boldsymbol{p}(t)=[p_1 (t),...,p_N (t)] $ can be written as $\frac{d\boldsymbol{p}(t)}{dt}=\mathcal{L} \boldsymbol{p}(t)$, where the entries of $\mathcal{L}$ are given by
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{ij}=k_{ij}-\delta_{ij}\sum_l k_{il}.
\end{equation}
Here, $k_{ij}\equiv \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} p(j,t|i,0)/t $ is the transition rate from state $i$ to state $j$.

Since the stochastic matrix $\mathcal{L}$ is a positive matrix, the largest eigenvalue of it is $0$. I am interested in the first nontrivial eigenvalue $\lambda$ (the nonzero eigenvalue with the smallest modulus of its real part) of the matrix $\mathcal{L}$, whose real part bounds the mixing time of the Markov process. My question is, if $\lambda=-\lambda_R\pm i\lambda_I$, is that possible to find an upper bound of the quantity $\frac{\lambda_I}{\lambda_R}$ when $K$ is not reversible? Now there is a conjecture that the upper bound is
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\lambda_I}\sum_{ij}\pi_{i} k_{ij}\ln \frac{k_{ij}}{k_{ji}},
\end{equation}
when the condition $\lambda_I>\lambda_R$ is fulfilled. Is that possible to prove this conjecture or find another upper bound? Any comments or hints would be appreciated.

I think this question maybe of interest for mathematician because it is an inequality connecting a stationary property of the Markov chain with its spectral gap, which is counterintuitive.